# How to find K first digits of the decimal representation of 1/N

Tags: algorithm, math

This is an interview question I came across: find `K` first digits of the decimal representation of `1/N`. It looks like we need just calculate `10^K/N` to solve the problem. Does it make sense ? It looks like I am missing something because the solution is too easy.

Comment: that wouldn't work because 1/8 == .125. If k==2 then 10^2/8 = 12.5, which doesn't help. The answer you'd want is 25, right? maybe I'm seeing this wrong?

Comment: The last 3 ? or first 3 ? ... I hope you know there are some numbers with the representation that have infinite digits... 1/3 , 1/9

Comment: Sorry. I meant k *first* digits. I am fixing the question.

Comment: @Ani yes I know that; my point was that the proposed solution isn't really right.

Comment: Michael - If it first K digits, then is it not straight-forward for the sake to easier division to multiply the numerator by 10^K and and take the digits? What will end up doing for the answer is divide by 10^K again so that previous multiplication nullifies.

Comment: @Pointy: It doesn't matter anymore; the OP has changed the question. :)

Comment: For completeness' sake, I would add a `floor()`.

Comment: Suggestion for someone writing up an answer: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22reciprocal+estimate%22+algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just implement grade-school long division:

```
int value = 1;
bool outputDecimalSeparator = false;
int digitsOutput = 1;
while(digitsOutput <= k) {
    if (value == 0) {
        Console.Write(0);
    }
    else {
        if (value < n) {
            Console.Write(0);
            value *= 10;
        }
        else {
            Console.Write(value / n);  
            value %= n;
        }
   }
   if (outputDecimalSeparator == false) {
       outputDecimalSeparator = true;
       Console.Write('.');
   }
   digitsOutput++;
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

The branch on `value == 0` is to detect when `1 / n` has a terminating representation of less than `k` digits.

Here, `n` is the denominator in `1 / n` and `k` is the number of digits to print in the decimal representation of `1 / n`.

Note that by changing `value *= 10` to `value *= b` you can print the b-ary representation of `1 / n` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Calculating 10^K/N can be extremely costly with large K's and small N's.

This is probably closer to a good solution: [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division). It's how we used to divide numbers before calculators. :)

Obviously, you should only perform this algorithm until it yields K digits.

Answer (score 1):

If it is first k digits, isn't it very straight forward to multiply the numerator by 10^k and so it becomes easier to divide by N? And if we need the answer, the decimal representation that is, then we will end up the dividing the result by 10^K again so that previous multiplication nullifies.

Comment: @user470379, OP had a bit of confusion in his question. If he just needs first K digits, then is very straight-forward as we do it for convenience.